# Can't access docker bind port from public IP

Tags: ubuntu, nat, docker, bindings

I've run portainer image using:

```
docker run -d -P -p 9000:9000 portainer/portainer
```

But can only access the web at port 9000 locally using lynx.
I allow firewall on port 9000 both incoming and outgoing, so that shouldn't be the problem.

> $sudo iptables -t filter -L -n -v | grep 9000
>       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9000

But I have hard time interpreting NAT table, which may be the suspect.

> $ sudo iptables -t nat -L -n -v 
>   Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 7 packets, 420 bytes)  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out
>   source               destination            415 24676 DOCKER     all 
>   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
>
> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 60 bytes)  pkts bytes target
>   prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)  pkts bytes target
>   prot opt in     out     source               destination
>       0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
>
> Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)  pkts bytes
>   target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> ```
> 0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
> 0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9000
> ```
>
> Chain DOCKER (2 references)  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out
>   source               destination
>       0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>       0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9000 to:172.17.0.2:9000

Can anyone help me out here?

Update1:

I tried the same command on another Ubuntu server with the same docker version but it works. The only difference in NAT table after run & bind the container is a record of POSTROUTING that says,

> pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
>       0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0

But I think this may not be related, or is it?

Ubuntu 16.04 
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be

Comment: The output of `iptables -t nat -L -n` does not show all the details. You need to include `-v` option to show the in/out interfaces like `docker0`. How are you trying to access the port 9000? What is the destination address?

Comment: Your rules looks OK when compared with mine (assuming the missing data is similar).

Comment: I re-run the command with '-v' option, I'm trying to access from browser in different machine with URL http://<domain>:9000 but no response.

Comment: Check if `tcpdump -i eth0 -n port 9000`  shows any packets (replace eth0 with the name of your public interface).

Comment: @AlexD I ran `sudo tcpdump -i ens3 -n port 9000` and try requesting it from other host's browser, still nothing come up. The server also has a web running on https (443) which can be accessed and probe using above command, so no problem with the interface itself. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping out in the comments,

It turns out I just use `nmap <host>` to check opening port and found that 9000 is not opened, though internal firewall/iptables say otherwise.

then I remember that the VPS I'm using has another external firewall layer which I've to config as well. Stupid me, but I learn the basic tracing process/cmds. Thx guys!